# sparql virtuoso bif:contains in a union

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I am trying to write a SPARQL query using the Virtuoso supported `bif:contains` relations to perform lightweight string matching. I want to check whether the label contains either word A or B, so I am using a `union` as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?o WHERE {
?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?o . 
{?o bif:contains "Ramji"} 
union {?o bif:contains "Manjhi"}.
}
```

However, that does not compile and throws an error:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: The group does not contain 
triple pattern with '$o' object before bif:contains() predicate

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?o WHERE {
?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?o . 
{?o bif:contains "Ramji"} 
union {?o bif:contains "Manjhi"}.
}
```

If only one of the clause in the `union` is used, the query works. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query splits at the wrong point.  Each part of the `UNION` has to be a complete pattern.  See my [query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%20%0D%0A%20%20%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E%20%20%3Fo%20%20%20%20%20%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Ramji%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E%20%20%3Fo%20%20%20%20%20%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Manjhi%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fs&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) and [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%20%0D%0A%20%20%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E%20%20%3Fo%20%20%20%20%20%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Ramji%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E%20%20%3Fo%20%20%20%20%20%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Manjhi%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fs&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) —

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?o 
   WHERE 
      {
         {
            ?s  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>  ?o      . 
            ?o  bif:contains                                  "Ramji"
         } 
      UNION
         {
            ?s  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>  ?o      . 
            ?o  bif:contains                                  "Manjhi"
         }
      }
   ORDER BY ?s
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use in this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?o WHERE {
?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?o . 
?o bif:contains "'Ramji' or 'Manjhi'"}
```